Automating Grading of Procedural Python Program
Let's assume you want to test basic programming skills of students. For example:

Write a Python module, student_submission.py that

assigns to variable myString the string "$stackoverflow is great",
remove '$' at the beginning
splits it into words
replace the word 'great' with 'awesome'.

Assume each step is 10 points and there is no partial credit.
I assume we need to mock print as well.

Students submit a single file, how should we go about testing/marking student_submission.py? Can we do this via unittest or pytest? It would be great if we could store the student grade in a dictionary, say student_dict = {'step1':0,'step2':10,'step3':10,'step4':0}
# student_submission.py
# Step 1: Assign a string to myString
myString = "$stackoverflow is great" 

# Step 2: Remove any non-alphanumeric character at the beginning
myString = myString.lstrip("$")

# Step 3: Split the string into words
words = myString.split()

# Step 4: Replace the word 'great' with 'awesome'
for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i] == 'great':
        words[i] = 'awesome'

# Print the final result
final_string = ' '.join(words)
print(final_string)


I see two options: (1) make the students print every step (print value of the variable, print the variable without $, print list of words, print updated list, print final string). Then you'll be able to run their script, e.g. with subprocess, capture printed strings and compare with expects. Also to defend your self from students just hardcoding prints like print("stackoverflow is awesome"), you can provide a template function def solution(myString) that receives the initial value, and which students need to modify. You can run the code with different inputs and verify it's not a cheat

Option (2): for unit tests, you need to wrap every step into a function that you can test. I expect there will be a ton of boilerplate code that your students might be scared of, because they'll need to put correct code at correct places in order for it to work

I like your option 1. Yes. I need to have them print and compare. But I need to come up a grading scales. if there are multiple points. Thank you so much Alexy. That was great pointer!

Adapting from the answer by @chikitin and @Alexey,
The for loop can be shorten for better readability by:
for t, s in zip(target_lines, submitted_lines):
    # ...


For any examples below, assume the following unless otherwise specified:
target_text = "Hello\nWorld\nPython"
submitted_text = "Hello\nWorld\nJava"

No partial credit (full marks or zero points)
As the question mentioned, there may by no partial credit.
def compare_text(target, submitted, partial_credit=True):
    total_points = 0
    target_lines = target.split('\n')
    submitted_lines = submitted.split('\n')

    for t, s in zip(target_lines, submitted_lines):
        if t == s:
            total_points += 10
        elif not partial_credit:
            return 0

    return total_points
    
# Partially correct
points = compare_text(target_text, submitted_text, partial_credit=False)
print("Total points:", points) # Total points: 0

# Fully correct
submitted_text = target_text
points = compare_text(target_text, submitted_text, partial_credit=False)
print("Total points:", points) # Total points: 30

Customize point of each step (same points per step)
You might want to reuse the code for different questions,
where every step has the same points,
but different questions/assignment may "value" each step at different points.
Of course, you can specify what is the default points per step (for all questions/assignment.
In this case, I have given a default of 10 points per step.
def compare_text(target, submitted, partial_credit=True, pts=10):
    total_points = 0
    target_lines = target.split('\n')
    submitted_lines = submitted.split('\n')

    for t, s in zip(target_lines, submitted_lines):
        if t == s:
            total_points += pts
        elif not partial_credit:
            return 0
            
    return total_points

# Give 5 points per step
points = compare_text(target_text, submitted_text, pts=5) 
print("Total points:", points) # Total points: 10

# When not specified, give 10 points per step
points = compare_text(target_text, submitted_text)
print("Total points:", points) # Total points: 20

Customize point for each step (different points per step)
You may value different steps different. Some steps may be more "valuable".
import numbers

def compare_text(target, submitted, partial_credit=True, pts=10):
    total_points = 0
    target_lines = target.split('\n')
    submitted_lines = submitted.split('\n')

    if isinstance(pts, numbers.Number):
        pts = [pts] * len(submitted_lines)
    elif len(pts) != len(submitted_lines):
        print('Error: Not all steps are assigned points')
        return
        # alternative, use `raise Exception(your_error_message)`

    for t, s, p in zip(target_lines, submitted_lines, pts):
        if t == s:
            total_points += p
        elif not partial_credit:
            return 0         

    return total_points

# Give 5 points per step
points = compare_text(target_text, submitted_text, pts=5) 
print("Total points:", points) # Total points: 10

# Give 2.5 points per step
points = compare_text(target_text, submitted_text, pts=2.5) 
print("Total points:", points) # Total points: 5

# Step 3 is more important, give more points than step 1 and 2
points = compare_text(target_text, submitted_text, pts=[5, 5, 10])
print("Total points:", points) # Total points: 10

# Forgot to give step 3 some points
points = compare_text(target_text, submitted_text, pts=[5, 5]) # error: not all steps have points assigned


as mentioned by @Alexey
After each step i will do ask to print print variables. If matches get full score otherwise, 0. One can use a simple code as follows to calculate the total points:
def compare_text(target, submitted):
target_lines = target.split('\n')
submitted_lines = submitted.split('\n')

total_points = 0

for i in range(min(len(target_lines), len(submitted_lines))):
    if target_lines[i] == submitted_lines[i]:
        total_points += 10

return total_points

# Example usage:
target_text = "Hello\nWorld\nPython"
submitted_text = "Hello\nWorld\nJava"

points = compare_text(target_text, submitted_text)
print("Total points:", points)

